# What's the meaning of "plays in the minds of someone"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ielts

What's the meaning of the phrase "plays in minds of someone"?

For example, in the sentence below.

> The significance of the IELTS is a fact that plays in the minds of hopeful migrants like Mr. Want2Immi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something *plays on your mind* if you're continuously worrying about it.

I've always known the expression as **play on one's mind**, but **in** is just as common (bad choice of word, since neither occur that much).

An alternative equivalent is *to weigh heavily (up)on one's mind*, as discussed (initially in French, but it's not that long) [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=801865).

I personally am only familiar with the expression in reference to a *single* mind - usually your own, when bewailing the fact that you can't stop being obsessed by some particularly unwelcome thought. But it does get used in respect of an oppressive concept troubling many people at once.

Comment: two notes: if a group of people share something (hopeful migrants) they can certainly share a worry. The other note is that searching through books I find examples of the phrase "play in the minds" (see http://www.google.com/search?q=%22play%20in%20the%20minds%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1973,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en , disregard false matches )

Comment: @Unreason: On checking, I find you're quite right on both counts. Disregarding false matches, both *on* and *in* seem to occur about equally. Though neither of them very often compared to how familiar *plays on my mind* seems to me. I must just spend too much time with neurotics who all use the same idiomatic variant. Whatever - thanks for the info, and I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: The expression used to be "prey on one's mind", but this has now been transformed by footballerspeak to "play on one's mind."